# Is Java not installed correctly? Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java

Recently when I write any code and compile it, then try to run it I get this exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

At first I thought there is something wrong in my code, but I couldn't find anything wrong with it. When trying to run a `HelloWorld` example that had worked before, if works, but if I copy the exact same code into a file `HelloWorld2` I get this exception again.

The code is identical but when I used `javap` to decompile both class files I found a difference. In `HelloWorld` (the original file)

```
"public static void main(java.lang.String[])";
```

and in `HelloWorld2` (the new one)

```
"public static void main(String[])";
```

without `java.lang.`.

I recompiled the old `HelloWorld` with `javac` and now when I try to run it it doesn't work and I get the same exception. None of my old code now works if I recompile it.

I've searched everywhere but can't find a solution to this problem - any idea what is going on here?

Comment: I'm out of breath just reading that.

Comment: This Community Wiki question lists the possible causes of this common problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5407250/causes-of-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-main-exception-in-thread-main

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may get this if you have your own class called `String` (without a package) in your classpath. It sounds like that's what happened. Here's a way to try to reproduce this - compile it and run it, and see if it looks the same:

```
class String {} 

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    }    
}
```

Once you've got the compiled `String.class` file in your file system in an awkward place, that will be used by default even if you only compile the `Test` class above...

Basically, see if you can find a file called `String.class` somewhere.

Comment: Or of course if there's a `class String` anywhere in your code.

Comment: Thank You very much master Jon Skeet and master configurator yes i have a file String.class and when i delete it every thing works